# Homotopy equivalence from torus minus a point to a figure-eight.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $I$ be the unit interval, and define the torus using the usual identifications on $I \times I$. I've shown that $I \times I - \{x\}$ (where $x$ is a point not on the boundary of $I \times I$) is homotopy equivalent to its boundary (and that it even retracts onto its boundary). Let $p: I \times I \rightarrow I \times I /\sim$ be the canonical quotient map. Using the retraction above, call it $r$, is there a way I can explicitly show that $p(I \times I - \{x\})$ is homotopy equivalent to $p(\text{boundary of } I \times I)$, i.e., that torus minus a point to a figure-eight?

More generally, if $A \subset X$, and $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $A$ (or $X$ retracts to $A$), for which maps $p$ can I say that $p[X]$ is homotopy equivalent to $p[A]$?

Hints appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried checking if the homotopy equivalence induced by the retraction descends nicely to the quotient?

Comment: @IsaacSolomon Sorry, newbie question, but what does "descending nicely to the quotient" mean? I think I know, but I'd like to make sure first!

Comment: Pretty much exactly what Daniel Rust has explained in his answer, i.e. that there is a continuous map $\tilde{r}$ that is sort of the "quotient map" of the original map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $r\colon I\times I\setminus\{p\}\to \partial (I\times I)$ be the retraction you mentioned. Can you show that there exists a retraction $\tilde{r}\colon (I\times I\setminus\{p\})/{\sim}\to \partial (I\times I)/{\sim}$ which make the following square commute?

$$\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\ras}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ \smash{#1}\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}}
\begin{array}{c}
   I\times I\setminus\{p\}    & \ra{r}       &    \partial (I\times I)     \\
  \da{q}     &              &  \da{q|_{\partial(I\times I)}}               \\
   (I\times I\setminus\{p\})/{\sim}       & \ras{\tilde{r}} &    \partial (I\times I)/{\sim}                        \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I think that $[x] \mapsto [r(x)]$ works...and I guess from here, I finish by show that the quotient of the boundary is a deformation retract of the quotient of the square minus a point, and use the map above?

Comment: Yep, so $\tilde{r}$ is the map you want to show is homotopic to the identity map.

Comment: Thanks! Makes things a lot clearer!

Comment: @RSalimi Sorry yes I forget the domain was missing a point. Thanks for pointing it out.