# $T^2 \setminus \{p\} \simeq S^1 \vee S^1$

Tags: general-topology

Why is the torus with a point missing homotopy equivalent to figure-8-space?

$T^2 \setminus \{p\} \simeq S^1 \vee S^1$

Comment: Consider the fundamental square $[0, 1]^2$ of the torus, with opposite edges identified preserving order. Chuck a point out of the interior of the square. Note that everything deformation retracts onto the boundary. Now do the identifications to verify what you get is really $S^1 \vee S^1$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661219/homotopy-equivalence-from-torus-minus-a-point-to-a-figure-eight